# Centering page Css

Tags: html, css

Hey I have problems with centering my webpage. When I try to center only the left side gets centered, while the right side extends. This is how my page looks:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the upper part there is a white box, and this box extends beyond my centered page.

So I want the right side to also be centered.

HTML code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="it_seminar.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>IT-seminar</title>

</head>
<body background="Images/dark-planingwood.png" >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="center">
        <div id="header">

        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    text-align:center; 
}
#center {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:800px;
    text-align:left;
}
#header {
  height:50px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:2000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: remove the self closing body tag. `<body background="Images/dark-planingwood.png" />` to `<body background="Images/dark-planingwood.png">`

Comment: Please include your code here.

Comment: A picture of code is not code.

Comment: Why can't you copy and paste your code here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask here. HINT: Post code HERE not a picture of code

Comment: clientIDMode="Static" dosnt change anything

Comment: Where did you pick up the use of the `background` attribute for `body`? That's not valid HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

The body contains a centered div, which is 800px wide.
Assuming the body itself is more than 800px wide, this will result in this:

[image]

And then you put a 2000px wide div, left aligned, inside the #center div. This will come out as

[image]

(or at least it tries to, but of course it gets cut off by the edge of the screen.)

So, the question is, what do you want?

- If you want the whole #header to fit in the #center, don't make it wider than the #center! In other words, remove the `width` from its css.
- or, it you want as much of the #header as possible to fit on the screen, take it out of the #center and put it after in the markup. I.e. after the end tag `</div>` for the #center.